# Ionic - How to Import scss or css file from node_modules?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to import this css or scss file *in my component*:

```
node_modules/plyr/dist/plyr.css
node_modules/plyr/src/sass/plyr.scss
```

Whatever I try does not work.

This is what I have tried already:

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'videoPlayer',
    template: ``,
    styleUrls: [
       //see below what I have tried to put here.
    ]
})
```

- `"../../../node_modules/plyr/dist/plyr.css"`

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load ../../../node_modules/plyr/dist/plyr.css ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load ../../../node_modules/plyr/dist/plyr.css

- `"../../../node_modules/plyr/dist/plyr.css"`

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load ../../../node_modules/plyr/src/sass/plyr.scss ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load ../../../node_modules/plyr/src/sass/plyr.scss

- I have tried both of those URLs without `../../../` and it doesn't load or give an error.
- I have tried both urls without `node_modules`, but starting with `~plyr/` instead. Gives the same error as above.
- I my `component.scss` file I have put tried this `@import "~plyr/dist/plyr.css";`

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8100/build/~plyr/dist/plyr.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

- And without the extension gives an error the file is not found or unreachable.
- `@import "~plyr/src/sass/plyr.scss";` also gives the file is not found or unreachable error.
- Without the extension also gives that same error.

How can I fix this.

I don't think I will be able to use answers like:

- Copy it and place it in your assets folder.
- Define it in your index.HTML with a link tag.
- Anything that imports it globally, I only want it in a specific component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `styleUrls` property from your component's decorator, import the scss from your component's scss file:

```
your-component {
    @import '../../../node_modules/plyr/src/sass/plyr';
}
```

It will be compiled into CSS and will be prefixed like any scss you would have manually added in your component's scss file.

Comment: Can't you just write it like `@import '~plyr/src/sass/plyr';` from within the the scss file?